# document.getElementById('id').src = reload not from cache

Tags: javascript, external, reload

i´ve a problem by reload elements not from cache.

Frist of all, my head:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"><!-- no cache-->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript">
```

So I´ve JavaScript var in external .txt documents written and changed by .php
My task is to implement this var into HTML and keep them actual every 10 sec.
I used following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="Perso_UHS_1"></script>
<script>
    function reldataperso(){
    var dper = new Date();
    document.getElementById('Perso_UHS_1').src =
        "PersonalkapazitatUHS1.txt?time" + dper.getTime();
    };
    setInterval(function(){ 
        reldataperso();
        alert("test")
     }, 10000);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="reldataperso()">
```

OK, this works with .jpg oder .html but not by .txt in the head. The Browser don´t try to reload, by the alert was coming every 10 seconds...

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have a look into using either ajax or the new fetch api.

Comment: What is `Perso_UHS_1`? An iframe?

Comment: Question Thread changed into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929647/how-to-automatically-refresh-external-data-loaded-into-javascript-variables-in-h

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that may be the cause of it.

1. No semicolon after `alert("test")`
2. The function `reldataperso` doesn't have a closing bracket (right before the `</script>` there should be a `}`.

Comment: The missing semicolon isn't an issue. Even if you're not fond of taking advantage of ASI, the `}` is just as effective of a statement terminator as the `;`. And the `reldataperso` does have a closing bracket. It isn't, and shouldn't be, where you think it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You have the 'cache-control' one wrong defined, maybe it fixes it

`<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>`

Comment: thank you, bugfixed ;-)

But Problem is still available: