# How to automatically refresh external data loaded into Javascript variables in HTML?

Tags: javascript, external, var, no-cache

I have digital information written as Javascript variables by PHP into a .txt-File. This information gets changed by a user at a different interval.

```
var ISTUHSXDATE8 = '21.1.2018';
var ISTUHSXTIME8 = '20:11';
var ISTUHSXROT8 = 0;
var ISTUHSXGELB8 = 0;
var ISTUHSXGRUEN8 = 1; 
var ISTUHSXAUSLASTUNG8 = '0%';
```

To show actual information in the HTML body, it´s necessary to make the HTML document load the latest version of .txt from server. [At the moment handmade by push the button and in webprojekt by setInterval() automatically]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<script type="text/javascript" id="id_of_java_var"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var dsts = new Date();
document.getElementById("id_of_java_var").src =
"https://www.juh-technik.de/StreifenstatusEA1.txt?time" + dsts.getTime();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code I can load latest version from the server for several .gif/.jpg/.html files by pushing the refresh button. The Problem is, this don´t works with .txt-files.

So my question is, how to refresh src of following line without page reload.

`<script src="https://www.juh-technik.de/StreifenstatusEA1.txt" type="text/javascript" id="id_of_java_var"></script>`

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I don't understand what the "bug" is. From your title, I first thought you meatn something along the line of `setInterval() ` (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), but the rest of the text is very confusing.

Comment: @Xan-Kun Clark-Davis, this code shows that bowser makes no refresh of txt-file.

Here´s example at W3. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOPMKYKWXNCK

Missing Result by reload can be watched by Firefox-Console. (F12)

Comment: Cleaned up language to make this a little more clear.

Comment: I don't get any errors. The example works exactly as I would expect. Although I have no idea why you would want to set the "src" attribute in such a way.

Comment: AJAX might be want you are looking for.

Comment: @JonB, Thanks for cleanup language. It was not in detail what I´m looking for, but after re-cleanup I hope it´s more clear.

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis : I choosed this way to refresh the global var from external Script by Javascript of HTML-File. Do you have a smarter solution for me? Maybe based on AJAX?

Comment: If you can, rename your .txt as .js this might help. 
EDIT: The problem is that your server return a `text/plain` Content-Type. The browser will not evaluate the Javascript in this case.

Comment: @ChrisR, sounds good. I´ve a html form send by post to php and php writes the StreifenstatusEA1.txt-File with form-filled information. I was not successfull by advise PHP to write .js-files. (only .csv, .html and .txt-files)

Comment: @ChrisR, the browser is able to understand the global var and works with them without problems (Tested FF, IE, Chrome). Just the refresh is not working.

Comment: @ChrisR, do you think the `text/plain` Problem might get solved by add `<?Header('Content-Type: text/javascript');?>` to `StreifenstatusEA1.txt`-file?

At the Moment i`ve no possibility to try, wait for sunday :-(

Comment: ok seems it´s not possible to refresh `src` of `<script>` Tags by function `document.getElementById('').src`
Any ideas for using other way to refresh external script input?